# I am trying to design a pie, but I'm not sure what to take into consideration

Tags: flavor, pie

I think a blueberry salmon pie with goat cheese would be delicious, but I am not a professional baker - just an amateur with a decent amount of experience and a good pie crust recipe.

So here are my questions:

1. Am I insane, or would that actually be tasty?
2. What things do I need to consider?
3. Chemistry.

Basically, if you were trying to make such a pie, what considerations would you take into account?

Comment: Questions about flavor pairings are off topic here because it's a matter of personal opinion. Everyone has their own thoughts on it and there's no "correct" answer. Can you be more specific about what you mean by "chemistry"? What are your concerns? Have you considered looking for similar recipes to try to find a recipe you can simply change rather than having to start from nothing? If so, you should consider posting it here and we will be more able to help you change the recipe rather than make one from scratch.

Comment: Question2: I think you should really consider the appearance of the resulting food. When the salmon contacts the dark blue/purple coloring of the blueberries, is that something you and your guests will be able to eat?

Comment: experiment, taste, experiment, taste, and experiment and taste some more; take notes; look at other pie recipes, check to see if there is a common thread between them.

Comment: And with what Max said -- you can experiment w/ the flavor by just making the blueberry, goat cheese, and crust separately, and then collecting some of each on a spoon, and taking a bite .  (and then adjust amounts 'til you find a good ratio, or adjust in other ways (remove stuff, add stuff, etc.))

Comment: I suggest serving the blueberry component on the side (at least the first time) . Maybe something like redcurrant jelly or Cumberland sauce, but made with blueberries. This may well have more visual appeal as well as allowing you to leave it if the pairing doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

We can't answer #1, because it is simply a matter of opinion.  You need to consider two things: crust and filling.  Since you already have a good pie crust, this is just about filling.  Flavor aside (as that is personal preference), you are going to want to consider consistency, that is, how the filling will behave when you cut the pie.  You are probably going to need to experiment a bit.  Traditional thickeners are flour, tapioca, and corn starch. Other considerations include visual appeal and flavor, but again, that is a matter of opinion.